# How can I return specific table columns with sp_executesql to LINQ2SQL or Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure include command `EXEC [sp_executesql]` and return the result with temp table `#UserDetail`.

I have a problem with return data via LINQ2SQL or Entity Framework.

I need get specific columns and map this columns to my business objects in C#.

When I create DataContext in Linq2SQL I get error:

```
The return types for the following stored procedures could not be detected
```

And in Entity Framework stored procedure return int not specific columns.

How can I modify this stored procedure to do this?

```
CREATE PROC [SUPPORT].[GetUserDetail] @userId BIGINT
AS
    BEGIN

        CREATE TABLE #UserDetail
            (
              [UserId] BIGINT NOT NULL,
              [UserName] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
              [Email] VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL
            )

        DECLARE @ExecStr NVARCHAR(4000) ,
            @Recompile BIT = 0;

        SELECT  @ExecStr = 'INSERT INTO #UserDetail
                ( UserId, UserName, Email
                )';

        SELECT  @ExecStr = @ExecStr
                + N'SELECT u.UserId, u.UserName, u.Email FROM dbo.[User] u WHERE 1=1';

        IF @userId IS NOT NULL
            OR @userId <> ''
            SELECT  @ExecStr = @ExecStr + N' AND (u.UserId = @userId)';

        IF @userId IS NULL
            BEGIN
                SET @Recompile = 1
            END

        IF @Recompile = 1
            BEGIN
                SELECT  @ExecStr = @ExecStr + N' OPTION(RECOMPILE)';
            END

        EXEC [sp_executesql] @ExecStr, N'@userId BIGINT', @userId = @userId;

        SELECT  ud.UserId, ud.UserName, ud.Email
        FROM    #UserDetail ud

    END
```

Comment: Why do you need dynamic SQL?  The problem is that the compiler can't determine what the columns returns from the sproc will be.

Comment: @DStanley I need Recompile via (OPTION(RECOMPILE)) sql query for specific filters in where condition.

Comment: Why?  What specific issues have you encountered that make you think you need to force a recompile?  Sounds like you are trying to solve a performance issue by out-smarting the compiler.

Comment: Or why not just recompile every time?  Compiling such a simple query should not create significant overhead.

Comment: @DStanley Yes, I want to solve the performance issue. When I insert UserId I only get one record and I don't need recompile and recreate execution plan but when I haven't search criteria I need new execution plan.

Comment: @Jenan But compiling and creating an execution plan for a simple query is not an expensive process.  Have you _measured_ a performance issue or are you just trying to avoid what you _think might be_ an issue?  You'll probably get better performance overall be recompiling each time than messing with dynamic SQL.

Comment: @DStanley Thank you for your comment. I got a recommendation to do this with decision "repeat compiling an execution plan is expensive for CPU".

Comment: @Jenan true, but so are dynamic queries, and CPU is rarely a bottleneck for SQL - Memory and I/O are much bigger factors in performance problems. The point is you need to have measurable evidence that it is a problem before you over-complicate your queries.  You're trying to fix a problem that isn;t there by creating different _real_ problems.

Comment: @DStanley How do you write my query? Can you help me create sample for my procedure with recompile in specific case? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear that you need dynamic SQL at all.  You mention a goal of not recompiling the query each time, but think about how you are accomplishing that:

- Creating a temp table
- Creating a dynamic SQL statement (recompiling if "necessary")
- Filling the temp table
- Selecting all data from the temp table

So you are doubling your I/O and memory needs to save a fraction of CPU time.  Your stored procedure seems equivalent to:

```
CREATE PROC [SUPPORT].[GetUserDetail] @userId BIGINT
AS
    BEGIN

    SELECT u.UserId, u.UserName, u.Email 
    FROM dbo.[User] u 
    WHERE (@userId IS NULL OR u.UserId = @userId)
    OPTION(RECOMPILE)

END
```

If that gives you the results you need but seems too slow, try it without the `RECOMPILE` and see if that helps.  I highly doubt that adding temp tables and dynamic SQL will improve the performance just by saving the occasional recompile.